# Como obtener el Nombre y el Nif de un certificado codificado en base64

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando obtener el Nombre y el Nif de un certificado codificado en base64. He usado el siguiente código:

```
byte[] decbuff = Convert.FromBase64String(cert);
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decbuff);
```

Pero el código me devuelve correctamente los campos del certificado, pero no las etiquetas del XML. Es decir en lugar de devolver , , etc. devuelve por ejemplo "\u0006\u0003U\u0004\u0003\f\u0019".

¿Cómo puedo obtener el XML?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso que te devuelve es UTF-16 aparentemente. Pero vamos, que en ascii traducido es `U\f`(con algunos caracteres de control por enmedio) lo que no creo que te sirva de mucho

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos un ejemplo del resultado del decodificador del certificado, y si puedes también la entrada base 64.

Comment: Estas seguro de que usas utf8 para generar la cadena ?